# Why my AWS volume size is different from the actual size?

Tags: amazon-ec2, hard-drive, partition, disk-volume

It's very wried to see my actual disk size is much less than the actual size. From the information, looks this disk is not be partitioned.

I have no idea why the actual size is 20G but disk size is 100G, and how could I find other 80G back?

The image version is stardard AWS Linux AMI:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2014.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2014.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2014.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09
```

[image: lsblk shows 100G]
[image: df shows 20G]
[image: fdisk shows no parition and 100G]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you expand the storage at any point?  It looks like the file system wasn't resized when the underlying storage was increased.

For ext3/ext4 you would use resize2fs to grow the file system.  For XFS you would use grow_xfs.  [More information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#recognize-expanded-volume-linux).